# Different set of Views for different user's roles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-applications, cancan

I am developing a rails app and I have **2 different user's role**: advanced and basic.

Instead of to hide links in the basic user's views (a.i. using CanCan ) I want to manage **2 different set of views**: one for the advanced user and one for basic user.

Currently I am working in this way:

```
 case current_operator.op_type
      when 'basic'
        format.html { render :template => "devices/index_basc.html.erb" }
      when 'advanced'
        format.html # index.html.erb
 end
```

But I dont like to specify at every action the template for the basic user ( { render :template => "devices/index_basc.html.erb" } )
I think there is some other way (I hope more neat :)

Do you have any ideas ?

Thank you,
Alessandro

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do something like in this [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/) [Mobile Devices](http://railscasts.com/episodes/199-mobile-devices):

in `config/initializers/mime_types.rb` add:

```
Mime::Type.register_alias "text/html", :basic
```

in `app/controllers/application_controller.rb` add:

```
before_filter :check_user_status
private
def check_user_status
  request.format = :basic if current_operator.op_type == 'basic'
end
```

Now you can just do the following in your controllers:

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    # …
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html  # index.html.erb
      format.basic # index.basic.erb
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: `Mime::Type.register_alias "text/html", :basic` it's an alias for html, but this way you can have two different templates depending on the type of user

Comment: What is the downvote for? It would be nice to know what I've done wrong to correct it.

Comment: I think it is a good hack, but I don't know if this is it a "best practice" because MIME is usually used for different purpose. (I voted up your response)

Comment: the mime type sent to the browser is still `text/html`, it's just a rails internal alias.

Comment: The only problem with this approach is that it expects all templates including partials and so forth to conform to the specified mime type. So if I wanted to load index.basic.erb, it wouldn't be able to load the rendered partial _partial.html.erb. Any work around to this?

Answer (score 0):

As you have only two different user's role you can do this

```
page = (current_operator.op_type =='basic')?  "devices/index_basc.html.erb"  : "index.html.erb"
format.html { render :template => page}
```

Comment: But he still needs to do this in every action. He said: "But I dont like to specify at every action the template for the basic user ( { render :template => "devices/index_basc.html.erb" } )"