# Rails: restructuring view files for different MIME types

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, mime-types

So I have a Rails application that responds to HTML, XML, JSON, mobile, tablet ... etc. Lets say I have "book" resource. Naturally, this resourse will require "index.html.erb", "show.html.erb", "new.html.erb", "edit.html.erb", "_form.html.erb" and other custom functions. As you can see, "views/books" folder will end up with many clutter files. I want to be able to separate them in subfolders inside "views/books" folder:

```
views/books/json
views/books/mobile
views/books/web
views/books/tablet
```

How can I do that without messing up my controllers? Is there a callback (filter) between controller action execution and view execution? If there is, that should solve this issue.

What make things more complicated in my application is that I want to reuse some partials in some MIMEs, for example I want to use "_login.erb" for mobile, web, and tablet. Then, customize it using CSS.

A similar question is asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10030887/render-mime-typed-templates-in-rails-that-are-in-a-subfolder-without-explicitly). But I am not satisfied with the answer, because it is pretty slow and does not solve my common partials issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are complicating things too much just to have a cleaner view directory structure.

First off all, I would advise against mixing the JSON vs. HTML issue with web vs. mobile vs. tablet issue. "Mobile" or "tablet" are not mime types, I wouldn't hack the Rails mime-type-based views functionality to solve this problem.

In our company we use different views for different mime types (json/html) and we use one HTML view that is forked inside based on the device type. It would be tiresome to reflect model/controller changes in three sets of views, one for each device type. Most of the time the views are the same or just with minor differences. We use [mobvious-rails](https://github.com/jistr/mobvious-rails) gem to fork the view code depending on the device. Wouldn't that be a better solution?

Comment: I think it is a generic way to support different devices, check out this link http://railscasts.com/episodes/199-mobile-devices. I liked the idea of mobvious-rails as well, but it adds complexity to the views section. In case of having MIME types HTMLers will have better control with less logic.